# Is it possible to solve this differential equation as a Bernoulli??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx} =y^2 -9$

This can be easily solved as a separable differential equation,but I want to know if it is possible to solve it as a Bernoulli

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, as it is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). However, you can directly read off the two constant solutions $y=\pm3$. The equation for $u$ in the substitution $y=3+u$ is then a Bernoulli equation,
$$
u'=u^2+6u.
$$

---

The other variant to get solvable equations is to set $u=-\dfrac{v'}v$  which leads to
$$
v''-9v=0.
$$

Comment: Okay thank you very much

Comment: Please, take note that “ricatti” in Italian is “blackmail”.

Comment: Right, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacopo_Riccati. I'll try to remember which letter to double.